# Can you Solve for $x$?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

### $x=a+b+c^{1}+d^{2}+ \large e ^{\normalsize67}+ \large f \large^{\normalsize62}+ \large g^{\normalsize27}+ \large h^{\normalsize14}+\small i \normalsize^5+\small j \normalsize^1+\small k \normalsize^2+\small l \normalsize^1+\small m \normalsize^1$

Comment: Is this an anagram?

Comment: It certainly looks like it might be, though in that case the combination of additive notation (+) and multiplicative notation (exponents) makes me twitch.

Comment: @Chowzen Would you like to comment on the fact that $a$ and $b$ have no exponents while e.g. $c$ has an explicit exponent 1? (I appreciate that the answer may be that you would not like to comment.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan It should become evident when the significance of the exponents is determined. Maybe I should add the [tag:enigmatic] tag to this, huh?

Comment: Is the capital "S" in Solve (in the title) significant to finding the answer?

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker I highly doubt that....

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker No, the puzzle is contained entirely in the equation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> The powers in the equation are the number of the moons (natural satellites) of the planets in the Solar System
>  Mercury = 0
>  Venus = 0
>  Earth = 1
>  Mars = 2
>  Following are the 'giants' which explains the bigger font:
>  Jupiter = 67
>  Saturn = 62
>  Uranus = 27
>  Neptune = 14
>  And the dwarf planets:
>  Pluto = 5
>  Eris = 1
>  Haumea = 2
>  Orcus = 1
>  Quaoar = 1
>
>
>  X = Solar System (or maybe the Sun)

Comment: wait, rot13(jung unccrarq gb prerf)! :-)

Comment: @deep-thought I was just thinking the same thing -- not to mention rot13(Znxrznxr)

Comment: @AdmiralJota Well, I've probably used the same planet list as Chowzen. I still can't get over the fact that what I learned in school is no longer true.

Comment: I knew that these numbers would cause unrest. :) Depending on the source, the number of `variables` (and `exponents`) can differ quite a bit.